# fastify-multer typescript , cant access request.file

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, multer, fastify

this is my first time using fastify with typescript, sequelize as ORM and fastify-multer, when i upload an image everything is ok but i cant access the file detail from request.file because typescript tells me request.file is undefined

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "nodemon index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "^4.13.0",
    "fastify-multer": "^2.0.3",
    "mysql2": "^3.1.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}





import { FastifyInstance, RouteGenericInterface } from "fastify";
import SliderController from "./controller";
import SSlider from "./type";
import { Model } from "sequelize";
import { upload } from "../../upload";
module.exports = function Slider(
  app: FastifyInstance,
  prefix: string,
  done: any
) {
 
  app.post(
    "/create",
    { preHandler: upload.single("myfile") },
    async (request, reply) => {
      console.log(request.file); //Property 'file' does not exist on type 'FastifyRequest<RouteGenericInterface, RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, unknown, FastifyBaseLogger, ResolveFastifyRequestType<...>>
      reply.send("ok");
    }
  );

  done();
};
```

this pic is my Error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQmKM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, apparently the .file variable does not always exist, the solution for me was to create an extension for this typing.

1. First import the request and reply typing:

   import {FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";
2. Extending FastifyRequest typing:

   interface CustomFastifyRequest extends FastifyRequest {
   file?: {
   buffer: Buffer;
   encoding: string;
   fieldname: string;
   mimetype: string;
   originalname: string;
   size: number;
   };
   }
3. Set the request type to app.post()

   app.post('url', (request: CustomFastifyRequest , reply: FastifyRequest ) => { });

See how it turned out, using your example:

```
import { FastifyInstance, RouteGenericInterface, FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";;
import SliderController from "./controller";
import SSlider from "./type";
import { Model } from "sequelize";
import { upload } from "../../upload";
module.exports = function Slider(
  app: FastifyInstance,
  prefix: string,
  done: any
) {

interface CustomFastifyRequest extends FastifyRequest {
    file?: {
      buffer: Buffer;
      encoding: string;
      fieldname: string;
      mimetype: string;
      originalname: string;
      size: number;
    };
  }

  app.post(
    "/create",
    { preHandler: upload.single("myfile") },
    async (request : CustomFastifyRequest , reply : FastifyReply ) => {
      console.log(request.file); //Property 'file' does not exist on type 'FastifyRequest<RouteGenericInterface, RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, unknown, FastifyBaseLogger, ResolveFastifyRequestType<...>>
      reply.send("ok");
    }
  );

  done();
};
```

**Warning: You must verify that .file exists and that the file has been uploaded.**